# Cocos2d-x Change MenuItemImage on cursor focus

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x

Using Cocos2d-x 3.4 on Windows7.

How to change "MenuItemImage" image on mouse cursor focus? (on Windows)

** I want "mouse over(hover) effect" to MenuItemImage. **

I know, how to create "not touch" or "clicking" button.

```
auto button = MenuItemImage::create(
    "button_normal.png",
    "button_pressed.png",
    [](Ref* ref){
        // do anything if clicking
});
auto menuButton = Menu::create(button, NULL);
auto winSize = Director::getInstance()->getWinSize();
menuButton->setPosition(Vec2(winSize.width / 2.0, winSize.height / 2.0));
this->addChild(menuButton);
```

But this method is not change image on focus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a EventListenerMouse to look for mouse over event.

```
//
//  MouseOverMenuItem.h
//  MouseOver
//
//  Created by Baris Atamer on 3/15/15.
//
//

#ifndef __MouseOver__MouseOverMenuItem__
#define __MouseOver__MouseOverMenuItem__

#include "cocos2d.h"

USING_NS_CC;

class MouseOverMenuItem : public MenuItemImage
{
public:

    ~MouseOverMenuItem();

    static    MouseOverMenuItem * create(const std::string &normalImage, const std::string &selectedImage, const std::string &disabledImage, const ccMenuCallback& callback);

protected:
    EventListenerMouse* mouseListener;

private:
    void onMouseMove(Event *event);
    void setMouseListener();
};

#endif /* defined(__MouseOver__MouseOverMenuItem__) */



//
//  MouseOverMenuItem.cpp
//  MouseOver
//
//  Created by Baris Atamer on 3/15/15.
//
//

#include "MouseOverMenuItem.h"

MouseOverMenuItem::~MouseOverMenuItem()
{
    _eventDispatcher->removeEventListener(mouseListener);
}

MouseOverMenuItem* MouseOverMenuItem::create(const std::string &normalImage, const std::string &selectedImage, const std::string &disabledImage, const ccMenuCallback &callback)
{
    MouseOverMenuItem *ret = new (std::nothrow) MouseOverMenuItem();

    if (ret && ret->initWithNormalImage(normalImage, selectedImage, disabledImage, callback))
    {
        ret->setMouseListener();
        ret->autorelease();
        return ret;
    }
    CC_SAFE_DELETE(ret);
    return nullptr;
}

void MouseOverMenuItem::onMouseMove(Event *event)
{
    EventMouse* e = (EventMouse*)event;
    Size visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();
    Vec2 locationInNode = convertToNodeSpace(Vec2(e->getCursorX(), e->getCursorY() + visibleSize.height ));

    Rect r = Rect(0,0, getContentSize().width, getContentSize().height);

    // Show selected image if mouse over
    r.containsPoint(locationInNode) ? selected() : unselected();
}

void MouseOverMenuItem::setMouseListener()
{
    // Create a mouse listener
    mouseListener = EventListenerMouse::create();
    mouseListener->onMouseMove = CC_CALLBACK_1(MouseOverMenuItem::onMouseMove, this);
    _eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(mouseListener, this);
}
```

Usage :

```
auto button = MouseOverMenuItem::create("button_normal.png", "button_pressed.png", "", [](Ref* ref){
    // do anything if clicking
    log("click!");
});

button->setPosition(Vec2(winSize.width*.5, winSize.height*.5) );

// create menu, it's an autorelease object
auto menu = Menu::create(button, NULL);
menu->setPosition(Vec2::ZERO);
this->addChild(menu, 1);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try MenuItemImage add to Menu.

```
auto button = MenuItemImage::create ...    
auto menu = Menu::create(button , nullptr);    
addChild(menu);
```

Comment: Sorry, probably, Intent of the question is not transmitted correctly.
I want to change MenuItemImage on mouse pressing or mouse cursor position is on menuimage.

Comment: If you want to change MenuItemImage, please add to the Menu。

Comment: I already added to Menu, I'm sorry intention is difficult transmitted.